# jquery-ajax request rejected

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I have a jquery-ajax that is called several times with different IP each time. Then jquery-ajax calls an action in the mvc4 controller that is in charge of performing the ping and then return the results.

From Internet Explorer dev tools, I noted that all the ping requests are marked as pending and they are served one by one. Once one ping request is served, next one in the queue is served and so on. What happens is that last ping requests suddenly are canceled/aborted/rejected automatically. Each ping request consists on 4 retries and each retry with a timeout of 5 seconds. However, If I set a lower timeout for each retry, for example, 750 milli-seconds instead of 5 seconds then all work perfectly. So I would like to know why the last ping requests are being cancelled automatically... It seems that last ones are rejected because they take a "long" time before they can be served.

I can post here some code if needed, please, let me know.

I am using jquery-1.10.2

**UPDATED:**

```
ajax({
    url: "/Tests/Ping/",
    data: { IPAddress: IP },
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json'
}).then(function (data) {
        // Do some stuff on success
   },
   function (data) {
        // Do some stuff on error
        // here I am receiving for last ping requests:
        // readyState: 0
        // responseText: ""
        // status: 0
        // statusText: "error"           
   });
```

Action in the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Ping(string IPAddress)
    {
       (...)
       System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping pinger = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
       (...)
        string data = new String('a', 32);
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        int timeout = 5000;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            reply = pinger.Send(IPAddress, timeout, buffer);
            (...)
        }

        (...)
        Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
        Response.StatusCode = (int)(packetsLost < 4 ? HttpStatusCode.OK : HttpStatusCode.NotFound);

        return new JsonResult()
        {
                Data = new
                {
                    sent = 4,
                    received = 4- packetsLost,
                    lost = packetsLost,
                    percentLost = (int)(packetsLost / 4* 100)
                }
        }
    }
```

See that (...) means more code. Also I need to return http status code plus json object in order to force jquery-ajax call to be entered in the success or error section in 'then'. This code is working ok for a lot of ping requests but as said, the last ping requests that do exactly the same as previous that went ok, are marked as cancelled/aborted/rejected.

Comment: Please add code to show the issue.

Comment: You're making ajax requests to different hosts - how exactly? Do the target hosts respond with appropriate CORS headers?

Comment: Post updated. See above.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Chrome or Firefox console? XHR request should show up there with all the request and response headers.

Comment: @HMR in firefox seems to work but not in internet explorer 10. In internet explorer I cannot see any type of information for those cancelled as they have been cancelled before they could be processed.

Comment: @Pointy as said to HMR I cannot see CORS headers for those ping requests that have been rejected. What happens is that they are rejected before they can be processed and then when they are being to be processed (as they have been rejected previously) then a responseText is sent as empty.

Comment: Ah so the IP address is just a parameter to an API. Got it. Well I don't see how this could be browser dependent, or even have anything to do with the client at all. The server does all the actual pinging, and the client just sits there waiting for a response.

Comment: Looking at your JS code it doesn't seem to be needing CORS. This is poorly implemented in IE 8 and 9 I think and jQuery $.ajax won't work if your requests need CORS. In IE, could you press F12 and in the network tab click "start capturing" See if you get any more information about what is wrong with the XHR request.

Comment: @Pointy you are right. This is how it works.

Comment: @HMR See this screenshot: http://snag.gy/wKVyh.jpg pay attention to the last three pings (they are cancelled) and if I do double click on one of them, all the info is empty except and I can only obtain intervals and below: http://snag.gy/PUfYG.jpg   (sorry this is in spanish)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the last requests have the same post data, there may be some browser caching issue going on. I would add a cache-buster parameter to be safe.
2. Your jquery ajax calls are likely running into a timeout scenario. From the jquery docs

> timeout
>
> Type: Number
>
> Set a timeout (in milliseconds) for the request.
>   This will override any global timeout set with $.ajaxSetup(). The
>   timeout period starts at the point the $.ajax call is made; if several
>   other requests are in progress and the browser has no connections
>   available, it is possible for a request to time out before it can be
>   sent.

The reason they are timing out is because all browsers will automatically queue multiple requests to the same host so that there are a maximum of 2 concurrent requests at any given time. So if you request 3 files from www.example.com, the 3rd one won't start being requested until the first two are done.

You can get around this by:

- **Preferably** Queueing subsequent requests manually when previous requests complete, not all at once. I say prefarably because you retain the most visibility into what's actually going on, rather than the browser or jquery hiding it from you.
- Changing the timeout given to jquery
- Sharding your domains. (ie. shard1.example.com/Tests/Pin, shard2.example.com/Test/Ping, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of sending separate request for each IP address you could do the following -

1. pass a JSON array containing all the IP addresses to the webservice in one call.
2. modify your web service to create a thread for each IP and ping it.
3. then send a JSON array containing the IPs and their stats back to client.
4. parse the array at client side to display them.
5. remember to use `thread.join` to make your webreference main thread wait for the ping threads to complete, else the ping threads will be terminated before they can complete their task.